# What does this line of Golang do exactly? Why pointers? Why the 0 param?

Tags: postgresql, go

I was following [this tutorial](http://www.alexedwards.net/blog/practical-persistence-sql) on PostgreSQL in Go and it has the following line:

```
  bks := make([]*Book, 0)
```

Which is part of the bigger code block:

```
  bks := make([]*Book, 0)
  for rows.Next() {
    bk := new(Book)
    err := rows.Scan(&bk.isbn, &bk.title, &bk.author, &bk.price)
    if err != nil {
      log.Fatal(err)
    }
    bks = append(bks, bk)
  }
```

Why does the author pass 0 in `make`? I understand that's the length, but why 0 length? And why is it an array of pointers instead of an array of books? Wouldn't you want a slice so you can insert books arbitrarily into it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Wouldn't you want a slice so you can insert books arbitrarily into it?

`make([]Type, initLength)` creates a slice of values of type `Type`. When `initLength > 0` then the slice is pre-filled with that many number of zero-value instances of type `Type`. In this case the author doesn't want to have any zero-values, and instead chooses to append non-zero values as they're received from the DB. So `bks` is indeed a slice.

Example: http://play.golang.org/p/g0dALT-sLn

More information: http://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals

> And why is it a *slice* of pointers instead of an *slice* of books?

This is hard to answer without more context. Using a pointer to Book will allow you to store `nil` values, which might be useful depending on how `bks` is used.

The tutorial you linked to doesn't show `bks` being used in any way that makes use of the fact the values are pointers. You could probably convert the slice to type `[]Book` without any problems.

Comment: You can also pre-initialize the *capacity* of the slice with `make(T, 0, cap)` - this is useful when you know how many results (or at least, the minimum number) you'll have.